# install openshift phppgadmin cartridge failed: manifest not available. why?

Tags: postgresql, openshift, phppgadmin

I tried to install phppgadmin. I got manifest was not available (status code: 404).

May I know why?

```
rhc cartridge add https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin.git/metadata/manifest.yml -a python

The cartridge 'https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin.git/metadata/manifest.yml' will be downloaded and installed
Adding https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin.git/metadata/manifest.yml to application 'python' ...

The cartridge manifest at 'https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin.git/metadata/manifest.yml' was not available (status code: 404).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>rhc cartridge add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin/master/metadata/manifest.yml -a <appname>
```

Comment: The cartridge will be installed but cannot be access by https://app.domain.rhcloud.com/phppgadmin. Do I need to install it or create some link? Thanks.

Comment: OK, it is silly. phppgadmin will need a php server, but I tested it on a python app).

Comment: Hmm, yes I tried on my Java application but the /phppgadmin doesn't work. I'm not sure what else needs to be done to make this work.